# os.system not writing in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, os.system

i have a simple test file i created in order to use vmd (a program for my job)
This test file is as simple as :

```
import os

os.system("vmd -eofexit < VMD_script.tcl -args 3spi_cholesterol")
```

Basically, im using os.system to launch a program name vmd with another script i wrote and im giving it one argument. What i found it is that when i run this test script, i get nothing done but if i just go in terminal and write :

```
vmd -eofexit < VMD_script.tcl -args 3spi_cholesterol
```

everything works perfectly. Is there anything im doing wrong with os.system? I have been using this line for a while now but on linux and it was working perfectly, could it be a mac issue?

Thanks allot

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739239/python-how-to-get-stdout-after-running-os-system)

Comment: I suggest using subprocess.Popen instead. According to [the accepted answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system), Popen is a more flexible replacement of os.system.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
ls_output = subprocess.check_output(['vmd', '-eofexit', '<', 'VMD_script.tcl', '-args', '3spi_cholesterol'])
```