# Save result of command "adb devices" in a variable

Tags: android, python-2.7, automation, adb

I am working on Automation part.I am running adb command via os.system("adb devices") in python.

I want to save output of command "adb devices" in variable because I want to compare device id which ever I am getting from adb devices and fastboot devices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to get stdout after running os.system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739239/python-how-to-get-stdout-after-running-os-system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
    print line
```

Compare line with your value

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `AdbClient` from [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import AdbClient

for device in AdbClient().getDevices():
    print device
```

to list all devices and its properties, like serialno.

Comment: This would make more sense in the current context! :)